# trigger change event except condition jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#query_txt').change(function() {
  return window.location = $('#query_txt').data('url') + '/searches?query=' + $('#query_txt').val();
});
```

This event is triggered when it's made a change on input field `#query_txt`

However I want execute this code **unless** a user click on this link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
```

I have tried with this version with **coffeescript** but is not working:

```
unless $(".select2-search-choice-close").click()
  $('#query_txt').change ->
    window.location = $('#query_txt').data('url') + '/searches?query=' + $('#query_txt').val()
```

**How can I do it?
Thank you!**

Comment: The fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586879/when-click-on-close-button-and-when-click-on-suggestions-text-with-select2

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this question is in [when click on close button and when click on suggestions text with select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586879/when-click-on-close-button-and-when-click-on-suggestions-text-with-select2).

Select2 returns an object in callback and it is possible check if it's added or removed there.  Thank you to Eru.

Answer (score 1):

Make a condition flag `true` when you click it. Or unbind to `change` in the click handler for your link.

Comment: Thank you can you paste a code example for this question? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#"  class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>

var buttonClicked = false;
 $('#query_txt').change(function() {
     if(buttonClicked)
     window.location = $('#query_txt').data('url') + '/searches?query=' +  $('#query_txt').val();
  });
$(".select2-search-choice-close").click(function(){
  buttonClicked = true;
   return false;
});
```

Comment: With this code my redirect `window.location = $('#query_txt').data('url') + '/searches?query=' +  $('#query_txt').val();` is not fired up and is not working. Now, with this code, when I click on `<a href="#"  class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>` is working fine however disable my redirect!

Comment: OK, I disabled default behaviour of anchor tag, is that fine?

Comment: Excuse me, but the same behavior is happening :(. I'm using http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/ if you are interested