# when click on close button and when click on suggestions text with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I want check if a user click on select2 close button or only it's triggered a change event. This is my select2 input:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :query, params[:query], :id => "query_txt" %>
```

On my coffeescript file:

```
$('#query_txt').select2(
   #select2 options here, ajax, initSelection...etc
   #
   #
   #
   $("#query_txt").on "change", (e) ->
     if ($(".select2-search-choice-close").click ->)
       console.log "click on close"
 )
```

The problem is that if I click on **suggestions text** I can see the text **"click on close"** on my console.

In other words, If you click on **x/remove button** as in this image:

[image]

the same behavior happens if you click in **suggestions text** as in this image:

[image]

You can see a example code in http://jsfiddle.net/nqWNJ/9/

**My question is how I can know when a user clicks on suggestions text or click on the close button.**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add another event that will trigger on click.

```
$queryTxt = $('#query_txt') #cache object
$queryTxt.select2(
  #select2 options here, ajax, initSelection...etc
  #
  #
  #
)
$queryTxt.on 'change', (obj) ->
  console.log 'clicked on close' if obj.removed
  console.log 'change was triggered'
```

Comment: It's not working I can see the same event triggered. For this case the event triggered is `console.log 'change was triggered'`. Thank you!

Comment: so probably the content is created dynamically. Try to use create a delegation of click event then.

Comment: Excuse me, but I have the same problem, this fix is not working for me. I'm sorry, I keep seeing the same message `change was triggered` for both situations.  Thank you!

Comment: Yeaahh, I have added a example code in http://jsfiddle.net/nqWNJ/9/. I have update my question. Thank you!

Comment: ok, I looked into docs. It seems select2 plugins is delegating all events to input so the delegation I wrote won't work because the input is always the target. However, I found a solution and it's really simple. Select2 returns an object in callback and you can check if it's added or removed there. I edited the code.

Comment: Heyyy Eru Thank you now is working fine :D. Thank you very much for your help!. Regards!